# How to prevent password from displaying in ruby template file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I am pulling down some html via a login. Is there anyway to have my password not typed out in plain text in the code? Is there some obfuscation technique I could use?

Ideally I would like a file that contains my password that is separate from the source code that I would like to share. Something that loads the password kept in \docs\mypass.txt would work great. I could then modify this to do a simple unscramble of my real password so I could keep a scrambled version in mypass.txt

There has to be some easy way to do a find and replace on `<<mysecretepassword>>` and source it from a text file.

```
<% register.ZServLogin.grabItems("ClimbElCap", "<<mysecretpassword>>").each do |item| %>
```

Comment: Presumably, you can use ruby in a ruby template file. With ruby you can read files (`File.read("filename.txt")`), read the environment (`ENV["MY_ENV_VARIABLE"]`) and do all other kinds of magic.

Comment: Thanks PSkocik this is the answer I choose. The others are too complicated for the project's current scope.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, not to be taken heavily, you should **never** store your password as plain text in any file. And while you can obfuscate your password, where there is a lock there is always a key and keys can be duplicated. What I am trying to say is passwords can be unscrambled. Instead, try storing your password as a hash! I would use the module ruby provides called `Digest` however ruby does have some built in hash methods. ( But I will let you explore that area )

Example time! Lets assume that you want the user to provide a password and you want to store that password in a text file for later. You also want to be able to verify whether or not the password a user enters is correct. Lets begin:

```
#first you need to require the module
require 'digest'

#then you need to get the password from the user 
input = gets.chomp

#now the magic begins, using the digest module we are going to turn the password into a has
password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(input)

#and you can store it where ever and how ever you would like. ( If you are worried about corrupting your file you may want to look into PStore. A great class for persistence ) 
write = File.open("password.txt",'w') do |file|
  file.write(password)
end

#Lets say the program ends there but now we want to have the user login
puts "Login!"
print "Username: "
user = gets.chomp
print "Password: "
pass = gets.chomp

#Now in order for him to login we need to compare his password with the one stored in the file
read = File.read("password.txt")

pass = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass)

puts pass == read ? "Passwords match : "Please try again"
```

Obviously there is a lot that needs to be done for this to work in your case. But I am just trying to give you options that you may or may not want to consider. Thanks and

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect example in which you want to use the `config/secrets.yml` that was introduced in Rails 4.1 (See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml). Or a similar gem like Figaro (see: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).

In a nutshell: Add your secret keys into `config/secrets.yml`:

```
development:
  foo_api_key: 'a-dummy-development-key'
production:
  foo_api_key: 'super-secret-production-key'
```

You should not add this file to your version controll system, unless you load the production keys from your `ENV` like this:

```
production:
  foo_api_key: <%= ENV['super-secret-production-key'] %>
```

In your code you can use that keys like this:

```
...grabItems("ClimbElCap", Rails.application.secrets.foo_api_key)
```